# Reference a method from another class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda

I'm doing this:

```
distanceFunc = lambda do |a,b|
  Leven.wordLevenWithOps(a, b)
end
links = prims(phrases, &distanceFunc)
```

It works but I would like to something shorter like:

```
links = prims(phrases, &Leven.wordLevenWithOps)
```

What is the right syntax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get class method of any class as

```
ClassName.method(:method_name)
```

and you can pass its reference

for your case(considering wordLevenWithOps as class method in Leven) following would work;

```
links = prims(phrases, &Leven.method(:wordLevenWithOps))
```

hope this help.